# Finding index of the point from array by X and Y

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a problem with finding/soritng points in array. When I want to find the point which is the nearest to the base point (0,0):

```
CvPoint2D32f[] corners;
...
Cv.FindChessboardCorners(...)
...
int min = Array.IndexOf(corners, corners.Min(p => p.X + p.Y));
```

and I'm trying to display index of the point - I'm getting "-1" value on textBox, like the the array is empty.

In fact it isn't, because I can display one element from it typing eg.:

```
this.textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(corners[0]);
```

And I'm getting in textBox:

```
CvPoint2D32f (x:179,143 y:60,15205)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant find it because `Min` returns the sum in this instance and not the object, hence the -1 result.

You will have to loop through it by yourself...

```
private int IndexOfMinPoint(CvPoint3D32f[] points) {
    int lowestValue = points[0].x + points[0].y;
    int lowestValueIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {

        int newLowestValue = points[i].x + points[i].y;

        if ( newLowestValue < lowestValue) {
             lowestValue = newLowestValue;
             lowestValueIndex = i;
        }

    }

    return lowestValueIndex;    
}
```

Comment: I can't use it because `int lowestValue = points[0];` gives me an error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenCvSharp.CvPoint2D32f' to 'int'`

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful I've just modified the type of `int` `lowestValue` and `newLowestValue` to `double` and it works. :)